# ROS2: Specify RTI Connext as rmw implementation on NVidia Jetson Nano not work

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to build my package with rmw_connext_cpp. It works fine on my PC (64bit, Ubuntu 18.04). Here is what I did:

```
vim .bashrc
```

then add line

```
export RMW_IMPLEMENTATION=rmw_connext_cpp
```

However, when I try to do the same things on Nvidia Jetson Nano, the systems shows the following error:

```
-- Found ament_cmake: 0.7.3 (/opt/ros/dashing/share/ament_cmake/cmake)
-- Using PYTHON_EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/python3
-- Found rclcpp: 0.7.7 (/opt/ros/dashing/share/rclcpp/cmake)
-- Found rosidl_adapter: 0.7.5 (/opt/ros/dashing/share/rosidl_adapter/cmake)
-- Found rmw_implementation_cmake: 0.7.2 (/opt/ros/dashing/share/rmw_implementation_cmake/cmake)
CMake Error at /opt/ros/dashing/share/rmw_implementation/cmake/rmw_implementation-extras.cmake:47 (message):
  The RMW implementation has been specified as 'rmw_connext_cpp' through the
  environment variable 'RMW_IMPLEMENTATION', however it is not in the list of
  supported rmw implementations, which was specified when the 'rmw_implementation' package was built.
```

Thanks!!!

BTW, I had already install **rmw_implementation**, **rmw_connext_cpp**, and **rosidl_typesupport_connext_cpp**.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/332283/ros2:-specify-rti-connext-as-rmw-implementation-on-nvidia-jetson-nano-not-work/) by [PowerfulMing](https://answers.ros.org/users/40080/powerfulming/) on ROS Answers with karma: 40 on 2019-09-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

To be able to use rmw_connext_cpp, you need to install Connext on your system. However, RTI doesn't provide Connext builds for arm64 platforms.  rmw_connext_cpp is not declaring itself as supported, because it is detecting that Connext is not available on your system.

More info:

It is necessary to install alternative DDS implementations before you use them: https://index.ros.org/doc/ros2/Installation/Dashing/Linux-Install-Binary/#install-additional-dds-implementations-optional

The debian packages for RTI connext are available under a [non-commercial license](https://www.rti.com/ncl) on amd64 but not on arm64 which is why you're seeing different behavior.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2019-09-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0